# Icons on NavigationView Items

Tags: android, navigationview

I want to know if it is possible to use my own icons on NavigationView items.
[image]

I tried to replace google icons to my own icons (drawable resources), but a square appears instead of my icons.

Comment: pl share what you have tried.

Comment: Can't you throw any custom layout into the NavigationView? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728842/how-can-i-add-a-custom-item-to-a-navigationview-with-a-menu-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying your own icons to the menu which is populated in Navigation Drawer, just add following piece of code in Activity.java file after initiating Nav drawer like

```
  NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
  navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Look at [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912893/how-to-set-user-avatar-for-navigation-drawer-via-url-in-android/33913761#33913761)

```
initImageLoader(this);
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.ivHeader);
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("YourImageUrl", imageView);
```